# Visual errors in pgfplots graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics

This is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, pgfplots, tikz, fullpage}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.5]
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {$n$}, 
        ylabel = {Number of Packings of $n$},
        xmin=0, xmax=10000, xtick={0,2000,...,8000},
        ymin=0, ymax=4500, ytick={0,1000,...,4000},
        grid = major,]
        \addplot[blue] table {totalTo10000.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What is causing the visual glitch of the x-axis and why is it a weird looking bar graph? I want the x-axis to display 2000, 4000, ... not 0.2, 0.4, ...

I also want the data points to be actual points, not a bar graph.

I will note it is reading from a file with 10000 data points, so maybe this is the issue?

The file starts looking like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you need all these data points? Looking at your plot you only need 3 point to plot it; is a triangle!

Comment: SInce we don't know the contents of `totalTo10000.csv`, we can only guess that these values are actually contained in this file or it has something to do with rounding.

Comment: What do you mean by “visual glitch of the x-axis”. I do not see anything wrong with the axis.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "a weird looking bar graph"? When drawing a line from a data point up to an other data point and immediately down again, then this is what it will look like. There is no visual error or glitch. You might wish a thinner line. Add `ultra thin` to your plot.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the necessary information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to see a [scatter](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-2dplots#sec-16.12) plot. So, you may use `only marks` option to remove the lines and leave only markers. the size of points can be controlled via `mark size`. Just use `scaled x ticks=false` to display x-labels as `2000, 4000, ...` instead of `0.2, 0.4, ...`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.5]
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {$n$}, 
        ylabel = {Number of Packings of $n$},
        xmin=0, xmax=10000, xtick={0,2000,...,8000},
        ymin=0, ymax=4500, ytick={0,1000,...,4000},
        grid = major, scaled x ticks=false,]
        \addplot+[only marks,mark size=1pt] table {totalTo10000.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The scaled x ticks worked perfectly. However, it's giving me an error which says "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size = 5,000,000]." Why would 10,000 data points exceed the limit of 5mil?

Comment: I loaded it in LuaLaTeX and it works! Thanks for the help!